# Why are all tables missing in data comparison in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use the data comparison feature in visual studio 2010 to see what's different between a couple of tables in two different databases. Both of the database are local and I can see them and query data from the tables I'm looking for. However, on the data comparison wizard, I'm not seeing a list of tables like I should be, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833273.aspx). The structural compare part work just fine. Any ideas I might be missing on something that seems straight forward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. One of the notes in the link I had said that the schemas had to match and there has to be a unique or primary key or index. After adding a primary key it still didn't work. Finally realized that case matters in the data definition. One database had camel case and the other was all upper case. Changing the upper case one to camel case made it work.

I didn't realize that case mattered on MSSQL, especially since the structure compare worked.

Additionally:  The Names must match.  I didnt realize one was plural and the other singular due to EF.  Check the names are identical.