# Visual Studio 2015 Schema compare not displaying changes

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-schema, schema-compare

I am trying to do a schema compare in `VS 2015` to identify what changes i have made to the staging database, but it is not displaying any changes for some reason. It only displays `delete` and `add`.

[image]

I know for a fact i have made changes to numerous stored procs and a number of functions as well.

I have been trawling the internet for at least 2 days now trying to figure out why this is not working, but there is not a lot of information to go on :(

**Tried the following:**

- Changing database target platform
- Matching database collation
- Number of different settings found under the schema compare settings
- Comparing LIVE database to my staging one (Still just add and delete)

Has anyone else experience this with their `Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition` ?

***Please let me know if you require any further information from my side.***

PLEASE HELP!!!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I had an issue with schema compare in visual studio 2010, and it turned out to be an issue with names and their case being different. Not sure if it's the same for you, but here was my question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5490651/636182

Comment: @xecaps12 Thanks for the response, that is not the issue though :(

Comment: I know this is a couple months old now, but I've got a similar issue.  Hoping maybe you found the solution.  In my case I have the compare trying to add items that are already in the solution.  Yesterday I made a proc in VS2015, ran the create script from vs, verified creation in SSMS, today I did a compare and you can see the proc being 'added' in the solution manager.

Comment: In response to myself.... The reason they kept showing up as new adds is because the scripts in the solution were saved as ALTER statements instead of CREATE statements.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too obvious, but it looks like the caret arrows on the left show the data is rolled up. Try clicking on the arrows (or double clicking) to expand the lists.